# Change color of first input word in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to change color of first console statement from yellow to some another color because it looks bad on a white background. How can i do this ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: `Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -ForegroundColor White`

Comment: @PetSerAl, this is working, but can i save this as permanent configuration ?

Comment: Yes, you can. It is what PowerShell profiles for.

Comment: Please note (as not _really_ mentioned by others), a `Command` isn't the first word in any case. `exit`, `if`, `for`, `foreach` and so on are Keyworads and stay green until you change them too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax highlighting comes from `PSReadLine`. To set the foreground color for `Command` tokens (which shows in yellow by default), use `Set-PSReadLineOption`:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
```

Place that statement in your `$profile` to have it run every time you launch PowerShell:

```
'Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -ForegroundColor DarkGreen' |Add-Content $Profile
```

Answer (score 14):

**Update:** Use this command instead for newer versions:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ Command = 'Red' }
```

#### Color list:

- Black
- DarkBlue
- DarkGreen
- DarkCyan
- DarkRed
- DarkMagenta
- DarkYellow
- Gray
- DarkGray
- Blue
- Green
- Cyan
- Red
- Magenta
- Yellow
- White